# Trying to swap multiple values in a user entered array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to take a user entered array and swap the 0th value with the 7th, 8th value with the 3rd and the 0th with the 14th value. I have to use a function to swap which is where i think i messed up. When i compile it says to few arguments for function swap. also, its my 1st time using pointers so i wouldn't be surprised if there errors with that,. this is what i have, thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap (int a[15], int *p, int *q, int *r ,int *s , int*t)  {

int temp;
  p = &a[0];
  q = &a[7];
  r = &a[8];
  s = &a[3];
  t = &a[14];

  temp = *p;
  *p = *q;
  *q = temp;

  temp = *r;
  *r = *s;
  *s = temp;

  temp = *t;
  *t = *p;
  *p = temp;
  }

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

int a[15], i;
   printf(" Enter 15 integers: ");
   for (i=0; i <15; i++)
   swap(a);
   printf(" Swapped array:\n %d", a[15]);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not an error related to pointers.

You called `swap()` with one argument, like this `swap(a);`

And while defining it you have more then one arguments. Like

```
void swap (int a[15], int *p, int *q, int *r ,int *s , int*t)  {
...
```

---

You do not need those extra arguments in the function definition.

Just change it to,

```
void swap (int a[15])  {

int temp;
int* p = &a[0];
int* q = &a[7];
int* r = &a[8];
int* s = &a[3];
int* t = &a[14];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A much better approach would be define a general function `swap()` and call it with proper required arguments multiple times when required.

```
void swap(int *p, int *q)
{
    int tmp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = tmp;
}
```

Call the above API something like

```
swap (&a[0], &a[7])
swap (&a[8], &a[3])
...
..
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i do this now nothing prints, i added a scanf(" %d", &a[i]); under he 1st print but i get nothing printed still.

Comment: Please try to verify the array you expect after taking the user input is correct. Try to print the array before invoking any swap calls to check if input array is correct.